# What is the best practice in Angular 8 to consume data from service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I have an app the all the state management architecture is implemented as Observable Data Services. What i'm trying to figure out is what's the best way to create shared lists and dictionaries that will be available via services. I know it's sounds simple - but since i'm new to Angular 8 - i still can't understand all the best practices with rxjs.

To illustrate my question - here is a service , a list of users, which i want to consume the data once (as singleton) and be able to get it easily by the components

```
export class ApiService {

 public users =  new BehaviorSubject<any>({‘users’: []});

 constructor(private http: HttpClient}

 public getUsers(){
   return this.http.get(‘/users’).subscribe((res)=>{this.users.next(res)})
 }
}
```

And here is how i consume the users list

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

public usersList: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(public apiService:ApiService) {

    this.usersList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    this.apiService.users.subscribe((value: any) => {
           
      this.usersList.next(value);
     
    });
  }
}
```

Now, i'm not sure it's the right way - since the logic seems to repeat in both the component and the service ... (i may be wrong here...) just to elaborate more - the users list should be a static data that should be instantiated only once .

Comment: You don't need a `BehaviorSubject` in the Component. Just use the one you reference from `this.apiService.users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as to how to handle data between components in Angular is: use a service

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

The angular team maintains as really good tutorial called [Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial), where they provide developers with a great intro to the angular architecture and its main data workflows. I specially recommend people to finish the [last chapter](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6), which is about data handling.

To answer your question, in summary, from the service you should not subscribe to the calls to endpoints. in your service, create the functions like this:

```
...
public getUsers(){
   return this.http.get(‘/users’)
 }
...
```

In your components you create [Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) to the service data like this:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
...
public usersList$ = this.apiService.getUsers();

...
}
```

and on its component template (notice the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) there), angular will do the subscription for you when you use the appropriate pipes:
(i am assuming your user model has a name and email attributes on it, just for the sake of showing data)

```
<div *ngFor="let user of usersList$ | async">
  <div> {{ user.name }} </div>
  <div> {{ user.email }} </div>
</div>
```